# Identify the after word given with word as input in NLP using collocation?

Tags: python, nlp

For one the requirement I have written the below code:

```
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import zipfile
os.environ['NLTK_DATA'] = os.getcwd() + "/nltk_data"

import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, ConditionalFreqDist, Text
from nltk.tokenize import regexp_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

def performBigramsAndCollocations(textcontent, word):
    # Write your code here
    tokenizedwords = regexp_tokenize(textcontent,"['\w']+")
    tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedwords if x != '']
    tokenizedwordsbigrams = list(nltk.bigrams(tokenizedwords))
    stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    lc_stop_words = [word.lower() for word in stop_words]
    tokenizednonstopwordsbigrams = [(n1, n2) for n1, n2 in tokenizedwordsbigrams if n1 not in lc_stop_words and n2 not in lc_stop_words]
    cfd_bigrams = ConditionalFreqDist(tokenizednonstopwordsbigrams)
    mostfrequentwordafter = cfd_bigrams[word].most_common(3)
    words = Text(tokenizedwords)
    collocationwords = words.collocation_list()
    return mostfrequentwordafter, collocationwords

if __name__ == '__main__':
    textcontent = input()

    word = input()

    if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/nltk_data"):
        with zipfile.ZipFile("nltk_data.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(os.getcwd())

    mostfrequentwordafter, collocationwords = performBigramsAndCollocations(textcontent, word)
    print(sorted(mostfrequentwordafter, key=lambda element: (element[1], element[0]), reverse=True))
    print(sorted(collocationwords))
```

My Output is as below:

```
[('fans', 3), ('car', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]
[('sports', 'car'), ('sports', 'fans')]
```

Expected Output is below(only the second line is the issue):

```
[('fans', 3), ('car', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]
['sports car', 'sports fans']
```

**Can someone please help with this? What I am doing wrong in this?**

Comment: Got the solution after lot of struugles:

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle found the solution

```
collocationwords=[i[0]+" "+i[1] for i in collocationwords]
```

Above code should be placed before the return statement